# How to count repeating values in an array (VBA)?

Tags: vba, excel

Assume I have an array that has the following data:

```
apples
apples
apples
apples
oranges
grapes
oranges
apples
oranges
grapes
bananas
```

How can I make the output look like this:

```
Item        count
apples        5
oranges       3
grapes        2
bananas       1
```

I am not looking for a pivot table solution, but rather a code in VBA.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Current Code I am using the following:

```
'Setting Up Dynamic Array to Store Fruit Selections
Dim MyArray() As Variant


'Counting # of Rows
Dim lRow As Long
lRow = ws.Range("A13", ws.Range("A13").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count


'Resize Array
ReDim MyArray(lRow)


For i = 1 To lRow
    MyArray(x) = ws.Cells(i + 12, 11)
    x = x + 1
Next
```

Now that I have stored all the fruit values in the array, how can I count the number of unique fruits and their respective count?

Comment: Share what you have tried. If unsure consider using a dictionary. https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/ . Add one to the value each time the key is encountered again. The keys are the fruit names. We can help with specific programming problems so sharing your attempts is important.

Comment: agreed, but do you know how I can do that if these values are stored in an array?

Comment: What have you tried? You can loop an array and use .Exists method of a dictionary. Without seeing any code I don't know whether array means the same thing to you as it does to me.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. i have added a sample of the code I used. Let me know if you need more information. Happy to clarify.

Comment: FWIW doing `Dim MyArray As Variant` and then `MyArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("A13", ws.Range("A13").End(xlDown)).Value)` would get you a single-dimensional array with all the values, without needing a loop and without needing to read each individual cell values - assuming `lRow > 13`.

Comment: oh thats much easier. Thanks for that Mathieu. Good observation - The dataset does start from A13. Now that I have stored all the value in a single dimensional array, do you know how I can figure what the unique values are and how many times they are repeated in the array?

Comment: You need to iterate the array, and somehow keep track of each value and how many of each there are - a `Dictionary` is perfect for this; key it with the fruit names, and if a key exists, get the value, increment it, then store the new value back at that key. Once you've iterated the array the number of keys in the dictionary is the number of unique items; declare a 2D array of that size (2 columns), populate column 1 with the keys and column 2 with the items, return the 2D array, dump it onto a worksheet, done =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a dictionary method. I note you are using column A for finding last row but that your fruits, I believe, are in column K. Each time a key is encountered again in the dictionary 1 is added to the existing value for that key:

```
fruitDict(.Cells(i + 12, 11).Value) = fruitDict(.Cells(i + 12, 11).Value) + 1
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TEST()
    Dim MyArray() As Variant, ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long, fruitDict As Object, i As Long
    Set fruitDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Select Case lRow
        Case Is < 13
            Exit Sub
        Case 13
            ReDim MyArray(1, 1)
            MyArray = .Range("A13").Value
        Case Else
            MyArray = .Range("A13:A" & lRow).Value
        End Select

        For i = LBound(MyArray, 1) To UBound(MyArray, 1)
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i + 12, 11)) Then
                fruitDict(.Cells(i + 12, 11).Value) = fruitDict(.Cells(i + 12, 11).Value) + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A1").Resize(fruitDict.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(fruitDict.keys)
        .Range("B1").Resize(fruitDict.Count, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(fruitDict.Items)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh that is amazing. Works like a charm. Honestly, still trying to reverse engineer how you did it but thank you for all the help!

Comment: With the above, is there anything you would like explained it more detail?

Comment: I have never used a dictionary method before and so I will have to do my own research, but will appreciate any high level explanation that you may have that can help me better understand and visualize the concept

Comment: Have a look at the link I gave. Essentially it is a structure that has pairs of keys and values e.g. Key1:Value1, Key2:Value2. Keys must be unique.

Comment: I am adding the fruits as the keys e.g."Apple":1, "Banana":1. And the initial value for each key is one (the first time of encountering the fruit). Each time I find the fruit again by matching on the key, I add another 1 to the existing value. So the value, at the end, matches the number of times the fruit is found.